# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "debajo de las piedras"?

Tags: expresiones

Con frecuencia utilizamos expresiones del tipo:

> - Para pagar la casa sacaron dinero de debajo de las piedras
> - Al decir que había tarta, salió gente de debajo de las piedras

Es decir, "debajo de las piedras" se refiere a "de por todo", buscando exhaustivamente o desde todos lados.

Pero me pregunto: ¿de dónde viene esta expresión?

Comment: For those checking this question: [We just reached 3 questions per day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En en inglés: [Leave no stone unturned](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/idiom-to-leave-no-stone-unturned) "*Is an idiom that means to do everything possible to find something or to solve a problem*"

La expresión estaba en la  página de traducciones [www.proz.com](http://www.proz.com/kudoz/english_to_spanish/cinema_film_tv_drama/803073-turn_every_stone.html). Buscando encuentro un libro que narra el suceso que pudo dar origen a la frase.

> Dating from the mid-1500s in English, to leave no stone unturned [...] It is popularly said to derive from the tale of an ancient king of
>   Samos named Polycrates, who helped the Greeks to defeat Xerxes and his
>   Persian Empire in battle in 479 BC. On realizing that the battle was
>   lost, one of Xerxes' generals, Mandonius, buried a hoard of treasure
>   on the battlefield, which Polycrates was determined to retrieve. He
>   purchased the field and began digging, but after several weeks had
>   still found nothing. In desperation, he turned to the Oracle at
>   Delphi, who advised him simply to 'turn every stone' - the more
>   systematic approach eventually proved successful and Polycrates
>   unearthed the general's treasure.

Extraido del libro [Jedburg Justic and Kentish Fire: The Origins of English in TEN PHRASES and EXPRESSIONS by Paul Anthony Jones](https://books.google.nl/books?id=rfqzBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Origins+of+English+in+Ten+Phrases&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAGoVChMIl4zw9O_pxwIVJy3bCh0gcwDM#v=onepage&q=no%20stone%20unturned&f=false)

Tanto en ingléscomo otras lenguas adaptaron la frase del latín *Omnem movere lapidem* y esta del griego.

Comment: ¡Caramba! Qué descubrimiento tan curioso. ¿Cómo supiste que viene del inglés? Realmente Google Ngram es una herramienta utilísima para estas cosas.

Comment: @fedorqui En un foro la frase era la respuesta a una traducción del inglés al español y corrobore los datos en Ngram. Descubierto poco antes que tu :)

Comment: Curioso... No dudes en editar la respuesta indicando el foro donde conseguiste tal información. Seguro que tal referencia puede reverlarnos más datos interesantes.

Comment: No me fío mucho de NGram, básicamente porque el equivalente griego de _no stone unturned_ se usa ya en [Eurípides](https://es.wikiquote.org/wiki/Eur%C3%ADpides#N) (siglo V aC), y dudo que no hubiese traducciones directas del griego al español ya en la Edad Media. O si éstas fueron indirectas, lo más probable es que pasasen por el latín y no el inglés.

Comment: Ahora que mencionas griego, quizás este libro que añado a la respuesta este en lo cierto! En el mismo siglo.

Comment: @guillem Pues si, tanto el ingles como otras lenguas adaptaron el "[Omnem movere lapidem](http://wordinfo.info/unit/3476)".

Comment: Parece que sí, aunque ahora mi comentario no tiene ningún sentido, ya que la respuesta es completamente diferente a cuando lo hice.

Answer (score 2):

La palabra hablada y escrita es relativamente nueva. El español es un hijo del idioma castellano (lengua romance que llegó a las Américas debido a las famosas conquistas), que a la vez es hijo latín (el cual tiene aproximadamente más de 2800 años de existencia y tuvo orígen junto a la cultura de Grecia), y así sucesivamente...

La expresión *debajo de las piedras*, ha tenido varios significados en diversos pasajes Bíblicos (Evangelio Apócrifo de Santo Tomás: *...levanta una piedra y me encontrarás*), los cuales, en su mayoría, provienen del arameo. No es tan importante saber de dónde viene, pero lo es conocer su significado, el cual depende mucho del contexto.

Para mí podría significar:

> Para pagar la casa sacaron dinero de debajo de las piedras
>    *(de donde no se imaginaron que había)*
>
> Al decir que había tarta, salió gente de debajo de las piedras
>    *(de dónde nunca se imaginó que vendrían)*

Espero te haya sido de ayuda.